# How to make a chain of calls of Web services transactional?

Tags: java, web-services, transactions

Let's says that I want to make two calls: one to service `A` and the second one to service `B`.

How should I make those two calls in a *transactional way*? For example, I call service `A` (it inserts some data into DB) and after that I try to call service `B`, but this fails; how should I rollback the insertion made when I called the service `A`?

Should I call a "rollback" method?

What if also this call will not work?

Comment: If you have a C service that can rollback the changes A made to the DB then you can achieve it by calling C in case call to B fails, else this does not seems to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Spring framework provides an abstract layer on top of different
>   underlying transaction management APIs.

Read this:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

    public Foo getFoo(String fooName) {
        // do something
    }

    // these settings have precedence for this method
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void updateFoo(Foo foo) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't answer to my question because is not rolling back  the insertion made on server side. What you did is just opening a new transaction and this is not what I'm asking for. Thank you!

Comment: Why you seperate your dependent services. You can create C service and call A and B method in C method. And add to C @transactional.

Comment: We suppose those are external services, therefore cannot be combined